# JavaScript close tab after window.open()

Tags: javascript, redirect

I've got a page which open a new window fullscreen but it still has the other page (the one which re-directs) behind so when you close the new window you are taken back to a blank page.

Is there a way to open a new window and then close the tab which is now inactive?

Currently I have some javascript like this

```
window.open("http://website.co.uk");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can technically use `window.close()` on the opening tab, but browsers usually will not allow JavaScript to close windows that it has not opened.  Can you redirect to some useful page that the user can use once they have closed the window?

Comment: Thanks I added a re-direct in it seemed like the most logical solution

Answer (score 0):

If you can add some JavaScript code to the page being opened, I think you can use `window.opener.close()` to close the original window. I tested it in IE8, the browser will ask for confirm before close the original window.